# Video View Looping with counter

Tags: android, android-videoview

so i have a video that i need to loop x times the problem is id not know how to do it. I have search it for hour but nothing so please if you can help me with this.

```
    video.start();
    video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            counter++;

            video.start();

        }
    });
```

I tried this but it don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
   video.setLooping(false);
   video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            counter++;
            if( counter <= LOOP_TIMES ){
                 video.seekTo(0);
                 video.start();
            }

        }
    });
  video.start();
```

Comment: it doesn't work because it is in a loop and onComplition is never actually called, but thanks

Comment: @Denis211, try my update. If you are playing a url, add internet permission.